# Having trouble with string array searching for another string in my function

Tags: c++, string, string-comparison

I keep getting an error saying I needed a class type when I have one stated. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong.
I'm having trouble with the bool SellerHasName.

```
  enum ComputerType { DESKTOP, LAPTOP, TABLET, HANDHELD };
  const int MAX_NAME_LEN = 51;

 class Seller
{
private:
        float salestotal;
        int computersSold[NUM_COMPUTER_TYPES];
        char name[MAX_NAME_LEN];

public:
// default constructor
       Seller()
       {
          name[MAX_NAME_LEN];
          salestotal = 0.0;
          computersSold[DESKTOP];
          computersSold[LAPTOP];
          computersSold[TABLET];
          computersSold[HANDHELD];

       }
       Seller ( char name[] ) 
       {
          name[MAX_NAME_LEN];
          salestotal = 0.0;
          computersSold[DESKTOP];
          computersSold[LAPTOP];
          computersSold[TABLET];
          computersSold[HANDHELD];
       }
       // Returns true if the seller's name is the same as nameToSearch;
       // false otherwise.
       // Params: in
       bool SellerHasName ( char hasname[] ) const
       {
          return (Seller::name[MAX_NAME_LEN].compare(hasname[MAX_NAME_LEN]) == 0);
       }
```

Comment: return (Seller::name[MAX_NAME_LEN].compare(hasname[MAX_NAME_LEN]) == 0)

Comment: it doesnt like Seller::name

Comment: line 4 `Seller ( char name[] )` looks like a function declaration, without a return type declared, and no semicolon.  The following 6 lines look like a variable declaration, but with no type specified.  Is this C++?

Comment: is this some C++ syntax that I am unfamiliar with?

Comment: @Michael it's called a constructor :). But yeah, the argument goes unused, and 5 out of 6 lines in the constructor body don't do anything. On top of that, the 1 usefull line, the initialization of salestotal can be done better with a brace-or-equal-initializer to avoid repetition.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the formatting of the code.  Looks like Josh Engelsma was having the same confusion I was.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the `Seller::` prefix in `Seller::name[MAX_NAME_LEN]`. There's no need to prefix class member variables with the class name; just write: `name[MAX_NAME_LEN]`.

---

Since you are using C++ and not C, forget about C-style arrays. Particularly, `char` arrays in C++ are almost always a bad idea. With `std::string` and `std::array` (or `std::vector` for that matter) things get much much simpler and therefore maintainable:

```
class Seller {
private:
    float salestotal;
    std::array<int, NUM_COMPUTER_TYPES> computersSold;
    std::string name;
public:
    Seller()
      : salestotal(0.0)
      {}

    Seller (const std::string& nm)
      : name(nm)
      , salestotal(0.0)
      {}

    bool SellerHasName(const std::string& nm) const {
        return (name == nm);
    }
};
```